# Android - get App from dependency

Tags: android, dependencies

I have two projects, let's call them App and Dependency.
Dependency is a some kind of GCM parser project that does ... things. It's hard to tell, because it's poorly written, company project that I am forced to use.

Anyways, I'm currently trying to change the part, where I show the notification. I wan't to filter that because sometimes I get notifications that were already showed. My plan is co compare ID's with GreenDAO database... which is implemented inside App. I have singleton class-manager for my database, that manages all database queries.

How should I get to that class from dependency project?
I know, that I should use interfaces, one way or another, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your classes are, but in general, you could do something like this:

**In Dependency project:**

Create a listener for receiving the list you want from the database, let's say `onDBRequest`:

```
public interface onDBRequest {
   public List<Integer> onIDRequest();
}
```

Then, in your class where you show he notifications you can do:

```
 public class ClassThatShowsNotifications {
     private OnDBRequest mDbListener;
     public onDBRequest getDblistener();
     public void setDblistener();
     ...
```

}
When you need the list of IDs to compare , you can just call:

```
getDbListener().onIDrequest(); //will return the list of IDs you need to compare
```

**In App project:**

Make your DAO implement `onDBRequest` and implement `onIDRequest` to return the list you need to compare later:

```
public class YourDAO implements onDBRequest{
  ...

public List<Integer> onIDRequest(){
 List<Integer> IDs;
  //do your stuff to return the IDs
 return IDs;
```

}
}

Now, the only thing you need to do is set the listener you want on the class that shows notifications. Example:

**In the YourDAO class**

```
ClassThatShowsNotification notifications = new ClassThatShowsNotifications();
notifications.setDBListener(this);
```

**EDIT**

If your class is a based service class, you can do pretty much the same. When you start the service you can can pass your singleton as the listener. You can work with `bindService()` or make a singleton from your service.

```
public class YourService extends Service{

  private static YourService sInstance;


  public static YourService getInstance(){
    return sInstance;
  }
  onCreate(){
    sInstance = this;

    }

}
```

Then, when you start the service

```
YourService.getInstance().setDBListener((onDBRequest)YourDAOSingleton.getInstance());
```

This would work fine since you have a local service, but you can also take a look at [Broadcast Receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: Okay, I think I got an idea how to do it.
What if, ClassThatShowsNotification is a Service type class? From what I gathered, listener implementation for services looks a bit different.